# Pushing all enemies in to an array and then checking collision with player

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

What I have done is made an array and after doing so I've pushed two objects(enemies) in to that array.

Now I'm checking if any of the enemies from that array touch my player.

```
    private function collision():void 
    {

    goblin1 = new Goblin;
    goblin2 = new Goblin;

    goblinArray.push(goblin1);
    goblinArray.push(goblin2);  

    //get all enemies in to the loop    
    for (var i:int = 0; i < goblinArray.length; i++)
        {
            var goblin:Goblin = goblinArray[i]; //datatype goblin to the goblin class 


            if (goblin.hitTestObject(player)) //if anything from that array hits the player then do this
            {
                //make that individual goblin stop

            }
            else
            {
                //make the goblin and other goblins move

            }
        }
    }
```

This should technically work, but I can't think of a solution, I would appreciate hints very much.

Thank you for taking your time.

Ps I've just remembered: what ever goblin the player hits, I want him to do what's in the if statement, not all the goblins, i want to target that goblin that's been hit, and hit only.

Sorry If I could not explain it at best.

Edit; I'm trying to accomplish a hit test where the hit test tests to see if the player is hitting the goblins in the array.

If it does hit that goblin, in that array, then only that goblin in the array will stop, whilst the other goblins in the array move.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what you are looking to accomplish? A better or faster way to do the collision?

Comment: I think you may need to have another go at explaining yourself because I'm struggling to understand you. By the way, I don't think you need both those Booleans. If goblin.canMove = true is it not implicit that goblin.cantMove = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what ever goblin the player hits, I want him to do what's in the if statement, not all the goblins, i want to target that goblin that's been hit, and hit only.

But your statement is correct, you will have that needed goblin...
If you want to stop your collision algorithm after first collision, you could use `break or return`;

```
if (goblin.hitTestObject(player)) //if anything from that array hits the player then do this
        {
            //Do whatever you need
            //Decide what flag you need canMove *or* cantMove ;) 
            goblin.canMove = false;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the `goblin.cantMove` and `goblin.canMove` setters do. If they're just Booleans, you will only need one - `canMove` can be set to true or false.
I assume you have a game loop somewhere else in your code. And when you update your goblins, if `canMove` is set to false they're prevented from moving.
If that's what you intend, then in your game loop code, I'd recommendand looping through your goblins and calling their `update()` method. Then, in your `Goblin` `update()` method check the goblin's `canMove` property and moving it only if `canMove` is true.

Comment: Hello, I've tried something like this, but it doesn't update because the hit test isn't working. https://gist.github.com/Moynzy/9412792

Comment: Don't put the ENTER_FRAME event inside your Goblin. You can run into trouble running a multi-threaded game. Also, as it is, you will be adding an ENTER_FRAME eventListener every frame - you don't want to do that. I assume you have a main Game class where your Goblins are created (the one where they are put into an Array). If so, put the addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop) there and, in gameLoop(e:Event) loop through your Goblins and call 'update()' on each.